# Are there any known issues affecting the use of the NOW() function in VB Script

Tags: datetime, vbscript

I'm having an issue with what appears to be the NOW() function.  I run a script with the loop below.  I first pull the current date/time into a variable which I save to my DB as a string.  When the loop is finished processing, I do the same for the enad time.  Finally I do a date diff between them to calculate the duration (depending on the data being processed it can take anywhere from 1 second to 2 hours).  What I'm seeing in my DB when all is said and done is the start and end times are identical but the duration is correct.  How is this possible?

```
While Not loRS.EOF

   ldJobStartDT = Now()
   LogToDashboard lsDatabaseName, "StartTime", cStr(ldJobStartDT)
   .
   .
   {Do Lots of stuff}
   .
   .
   ldJobEndDT = Now()
   LogToDashboard lsDatabaseName, "EndTime", cStr(ldJobEndDT)

   llJobDuration = DateDiff("s", ldJobStartDT,  ldJobEndDT)
   LogToDashboard lsDatabaseName, "Duration", llJobDuration
Wend
```

Comment: You need to check/publish `LogToDashboard` to make sure it doesn't store the current time (as Log functions often do). Now() is volatile, but it can't be an issue here, because you send stringyfied copies to that Sub.

Answer (score 0):

From Help. Your code is rounding it for display. See if treating it as a Double works better for you.

Date Data Type

Date variables are stored as IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point numbers that represent dates ranging from 1 January 100 to 31 December 9999 and times from 0:00:00 to 23:59:59. Any recognizable literal date values can be assigned to Date variables. Date literals must be enclosed within number signs (#), for example, #January 1, 1993# or #1 Jan 93#.

Date variables display dates according to the short date format recognized by your computer. Times display according to the time format (either 12-hour or 24-hour) recognized by your computer.

When other numeric types are converted to Date, values to the left of the decimal represent date information while values to the right of the decimal represent time. Midnight is 0 and midday is 0.5. Negative whole numbers represent dates before 30 December 1899.

Comment: Rounding values obtained by Now() can't be responsible for lost durations "from 1 second to 2 hours".

Comment: Lets just print it out as a CDbl and see what it says.

Comment: Also remove the CStr, it is unnecessary.

Comment: You should be using FormatDateTime (or do nothing) not CStr. Your problem is your variable name. Apparantly wierd things happen if a variable starts with ID. Both in VB6 and VBScript.

Comment: Actually more is going on. I removed Id, and started working. I put it back and it continued working.